# Create http request from cloud functions with header and response

Tags: flutter, firebase, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently developing a flutter app that sends some http requests to an external service, but actually, I keep some API keys in the app, and I want to secure them using cloud functions. How can I create a function that executes something like this? This is a Stripe request that I actually make from the app.

```
Future<Customer?> createCustomer(String userId) async {
    final String url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers';
    Map<String,String> headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <API_KEY_HERE>',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    var response = await _client.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: {'name': "test", "metadata[userId]": userId},
    );
    final decodedResult = json.decode(response.body);
    log.info(decodedResult);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        final customer = Customer.fromMap(decodedResult);
        currentCustomer = customer;
        return customer;
      } catch (e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cloud very well, from a Cloud Function, call the Stripe REST API with, for example, the axios library.

But since we use the Admin SDK for Node.js to write Cloud Functions for Firebase, I would suggest to use the [Stripe Node.js API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=node) (This link points to the `customers.create` method).

You can do that from any type of Cloud Function, e.g. a Callable one that you call from your app or a background triggered one, e.g. when a new customer doc is created in a Firestore collection.

---

The following search on SO will return many code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Firebase+Cloud+Functions+stripe

Comment: thank you, i solved with your solution!